# Overlay effect is not applying for background

Tags: html, css, angular7

I m designing login page .Trying to apply black background for login form but its not applying.It shows height for form-container 0.That's why its not applying .If I give manually height it works.Previously For other forms overlay effect was working .

```css
.form-container {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background: #000000;
  /* background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); */
  z-index: 2;
}

.form-content {
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 14px 6px #f3f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #f3f1f1;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="form-content">
    <form>
      <div class="form-control">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Email" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div class="form-control">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput type="password" placeholder="password" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button mat-flat-button color="primary">Log In</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way using flex `display: flex;` and to answer your question on why `form-container` height was 0 -> its because the content inside it was given `position:absolute` making it act like a div without any content.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

.form-container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-content {
    width: 250px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 14px 6px #f3f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #f3f1f1;
    padding: 50px;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="form-content">
    <form>

      <div class="form-control">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Email">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div class="form-control">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput type="password" placeholder="password">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button mat-flat-button color="primary">Log In</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works if i remove absolute.I want to form to be placed in exact centre of the page.and for that absolute is needed.

Comment: flex is the best option to do that, it will make sure your form is in the middle of your screen no matter what screen size you are dealing with. Run the code in full screen and you will get it.

Comment: Why is that div takes height 0

Comment: It’s because you were giving it position:absolute which makes the div “disrespect “ normal flow. You cannot calculate parent height having absolute positioned children.